# Parallel processing for display list

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, parallel-processing, displaylist

Is that possible to do parallel processing for display list on OpenGL? I am trying to find a way to accelerate my program. The part of loading the model to the GPU by using display list is taking too long (the model is very massive). Is that possible to use parallel processing for display list? Will is cause any run time error?

Comment: This does not make much sense, to be honest. What benefit do you expect to get from doing the data upload in parallel? If the model is massive, you should consider vertex buffer objects to more intelligently manage GPU memory; you can map/update small portions of the model at a time rather than sending all of the data immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display lists are shareable between contexts, so you can create a second thread with a second GL context sharing the objects with your main/drawing context, and compile the list in that separate thread. But you manually have to synchronize both threads *and* the GL server, so you must actually make sure that the display list compilation is finished before you can tell the main thread to use it.